# How to access rows with composite keys in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0, grails3

I'm creating a simple CRUD for a Oracle 12c DB in Grails 3 using scaffolding and while for simple tables which have an explicit integer ID column like this one:

```
class Config {
    int id
    String name
    String type
    String value
    String description
    int status

    static constraints = {
        /* constraints constraints constraints */
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort 'name'
        version false
        id column: 'CONFIGID', name:'id', generator:'sequence', params:[sequence: 'CONFIG_SEQ']
    }
}
```

everything works fine and you can access a given row's scaffolded views through an auto-generated link in the list view as well as with an explicit URL in the form of `config/<view>/<ID>`, as soon as I have a table with a composite key like this one:

```
class AliasFrequencyDict implements Serializable{
    String frequency
    String unit
    String description
    String lang

    static constraints = {
        /* constraints constraints constraints */
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort 'frequency'
        version false
        id composite: ['frequency', 'unit', 'lang']
    }
}
```

... you can't access the rows anymore (or I don't know how). Scaffolding doesn't generate links to the views in list view anymore and trying to access it through a URL like `aliasFrequencyDict/show/0/D/PL` (which would precisely be `/<view>/<frequency>/<unit>/<lang>` like specified in the composite id's definition) results in a 404.

How do I access the relevant show, edit etc. pages when using a composite ID?

Comment: It's probably a limitation of scaffolding, I guess you'll need to generate the views for this particular domain and hack them to your requirements, http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html. The docs do state they don't recommend using composite keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I access the relevant show, edit etc. pages when using a
>   composite ID?

There are many ways to do it.  For example, for `show` you could have a URL mapping that looks something like this...

```
"/aliasFreqDict/$freq/$unit/$language"(controller: 'aliasFreqDict', action: 'show')
```

And then have a corresponding controller action...

```
class AliasFreqDictController {

    AliasFreqService aliasFreqService

    def show(String freq, String unit, String language) {
        // have a service method that looks up the instance by these properties...
        respond aliasFreqService.find(freq, unit, language)
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Note that I used `"language"` as the request parameter name. I know you have a property named `"lang"` which is fine, but you don't want to use `"lang"` as a request parameter because of the locale switching stuff that we have built into the framework which uses a parameter with that name.

Comment: Oh, I see, makes sense, thanks a lot! I did go a slightly different route and added a method for appropriate redirection in the controller (like shown in step 5 here: http://grailsframework.blogspot.com/2008/05/composite-key-in-domain-class.html) to, I believe, largely the same effect as what you show here. The problem, though, is that even though these methods make the `show` or `edit` work properly, actually modifying the record doesn't work - I get a `AliasFrequencyDict not found with id null` when trying to update such a composite-id row. How do I make all that work properly, too?

Comment: Do the same sort of thing for the updates.  Add a url mapping that associates a `PUT` request with a controller action that will do the updating, supply the pieces of the primary key either as pieces of the URL or as form parameters, have the `update` action retrieve the instance (similar to `show`) and then update the instance with the values of the form parameters.

Comment: Oh my, this sounds rather complicated :( Will try my best though, thanks!

Comment: "Oh my, this sounds rather complicated" - I don't think it will be very complicated.  The update action would have 3 or 4 lines of code in it.